# $index not working in Nativescript

Tags: javascript, xml, nativescript

I've been searching for solutions with no luck, I'm trying to use the index of the observablearray but the console always throws and error and the rendered view doesn't display anything but blank on the label the `{{ $index }}` is written.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the index via $index as there is no such logic implemented for Repeater. You can create your own id for each of your array items and then use it as an index.
e.g.

page.ts

```
items.forEach(element => {
    element.id = id;
    id++;
});
```

page.xml

```
<Repeater items="{{ items }}">
    <Repeater.itemsLayout>
        <StackLayout />
    </Repeater.itemsLayout>
    <Repeater.itemTemplate>
        <Label text="{{ id }}" textWrap="true" />
    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
</Repeater>
```

And then you can get the specific item tapped with the bindingContext of the tapped view.

```
exports.onTap = function(args) {
    var item = args.view.bindingContext;
    console.log('item.id', item.get('id'));
};
```

Comment: so I really need to do it manually? that's somehow sad to have additional logic… :)

Comment: Or use a listview :) https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/interfaces/_ui_list_view_.itemeventdata.html

Comment: If you want to implement this you can add this code `dataItem["$index"] = i; ` after this line https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/repeater/repeater.ts#L150 and then you will have $index for your repeater - you will have to either link your tns-core-modules or modify directly in your node_modules folder after each npm install

Comment: Logged here as a possible feature request https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/3505